# JQuery Chosen Library Doesn't work with other JQuery Code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I am using [jQuery Chosen Library](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen). Everything works fine till now.

But now if I want to implement the [Generic Country & State Dropdown List plugin](https://www.cssscript.com/generic-country-state-dropdown-list-countries-js/) in my dropdown box then with `class="chosen"` it doesn't work. But if I remove `chosen` from class then it works fine.

Can anyone tell me why so ? and how I can implement this piece of code with Chosen Library dropdown style.

Thanks

Comment: `This version of Chosen is not currently under active development while we decide on its future direction.` You should probably find a more modern library. This one hasn't been touched in 4 years.

Comment: [Select2](https://select2.org/) might do.

Comment: Because [tag:jquery-chosen] hides the `select` and replaces it, you need to call `populateCountries` *before* you make it a "chosen" drop down.  Or call .change() on the element.

Comment: @freedomn-m Hi, can you please provide a demo like how you telling ? I am noob implementing plugins. Thanks